# Extract important attributes in Weka

Tags: java, data-mining, weka

That's rather newbie question, so please take it with a grain of salt.

I'm new in the field of data mining and trying to get my head wrapped around this topic. Right now I'm trying to polish my existing model so that it classifies instances better. The problem is, that my model has around 480 attributes. I know for sure that not all of them are relevant, but it's hard for me point out which are indeed important.

**The question is**: having **valid training and test sets**, does one can use some sort of **data mining algorithm** which would throw away attributes that seem to not have any impact on the quality of classification?

I'm using Weka.

Comment: You can try random forest with limiting number of attributes or PCA, but I would recommend using R and caret package

Comment: That would be good, but I've learned that my problem was solved using R and caret package. But since I'm learning, that would be cheating :-P

Comment: What I mean "use random forest" - I mean random forest in weka - if You use weka 3.6.6 - select module explorer -> than go to tab "Select attributes" and choose "Attribute evaluator" and "Search method", you can also choose between using full data set or cv sets, for more details see http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?68687-Selecting-Attributes-with-Weka or http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection

Comment: @java_fox, could you convert your comment into response? I will accept it, as this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment converted to answer as OP suggested:
If You use weka 3.6.6 - select module explorer -> than go to tab "Select attributes" and choose "Attribute evaluator" and "Search method", you can also choose between using full data set or cv sets, for more details see e.g. http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?68687-Selecting-Attributes-with-Weka or http://weka.wikispaces.com/Performing+attribute+selection

Comment: Thanks, "Select Attributes" was the option I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should test using some of the **Classifier** algorithms that **Weka** has.

The basic idea is to use the **Cross-validation** option, so you can see which algorithm gives you the best **Correctly Classified Instances** value.

I can give you an example of one of my training set, using the **Cross-validation** option and choosing **Folds** 10.

As you can see, using the **J48** classifier I will have:

```
Correctly Classified Instances        4310               83.2207 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances       869               16.7793 %
```

and if I will use for example the **NaiveBayes** Algorithm I will have:

```
Correctly Classified Instances        1996               38.5403 %
Incorrectly Classified Instances      3183               61.4597 %
```

and so on, the values differ depending on the algorithm.

So, test as many algorithms as possible and see which one gives you the best Correctly Classified Instances / Time consumed.

Comment: The thing is that I have performed classification on my training set with various algorithms and some yielded even 100% success rate. However, I was able to achieve only around 55% on test data set. That led me to think that perhaps some of the attributes do not bring anything to the solution.
But I was always using "Training set" option on the classification tab, not "Cross validation". You say that Cross Validation could help out achieve better results?

Comment: The cross-validation is used to see how accurately your predictive model is. In a few words cross-validation takes 9 parts of you training test and uses the other part as a test set, and so it can test how good your model can predict, using only the train set. I guess you got 100% success rate when you used the same data for the training set and for the test set.

Comment: Keep in mind that it is almost impossible to predict with 100% accuracy  when your training set is different from the testing set.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the topic of clustering algorithms (only on your training set though!)

Answer (score 0):

Look into the InfoGainAttributeEval class.
The buildEvaluator() and the evaluateAttribute(int index) functions should help.